# How to force a 16:9 video playback in VLC or ffplay?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I'm trying to figure out what is the correct command line switches to play anamorphic videos `2.40:1` (wider than `16:9`) in VLC and/or ffplay.

Like the sample image, I want to clip the sidebars of a `2.40:1` so it becomes `16:9` during playback.

I tried `vlc --aspect-ratio 16:9` but it will strecth the video losing its aspect ratio.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to clip the sidebars of a 2.40:1 so it becomes 16:9 during playback*

For ffplay,

```
ffplay video.mp4 -vf "crop=ih*16/9:ih"
```

I assume your video is square-pixel.